# Windows RDP cannot connect to x64 server from XP SP3+

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-vista, rdp, windows-xp

I have a strange problem that I can't seem to find the answer to anywhere online.  The issue has to do with using Windows RDP to connect to our servers.

Here is what works:
-XP/Vista client (any SPs) connecting to 32-bit Server 2003 machine
-XP (SP2 and lower) client conecting to 64-bit Server 2003 machine

Here is what does not work:
- XP SP3+/Vista client connecting to 64-bit Server 2003 machine

It appears that the issue is that XP SP3 and Vista clients cannot connect to x64 Server 2003 boxes.  After entering the username/password, we get an error message saying the below, and the connection drops:

> To log on to this remote computer, you must have Terminal Server User Access persmissions on this computer. By default, members of the Remote Desktop Users group have these permissions.  If you are not a member of the Remote Desktop Users group or another group that has these persmissions, or if the Remote Desktop User group does not have these permissions, you must be granted these permissions manually.

The issue is that the user is a member of the Administrators group, which has permission.  Also, logging in using the same username, but from an XP SP2 machine, has no problems at all.

I hope I explained this well enough, and any help/insight that can be given would be greatly appreciated.

-- Update --

We've tried installing the latest RDC version (from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084)), but no luck.  Has anybody out there experienced this?

For example, I have XP SP2, and my colleague has XP SP3.  We are both running RDP version 5.2.3790.1830.  I can log into our 64-bit Server 2003 boxes from my computer without a problem, but can't login from his.  Same user account on the same server, using same client software, but different client OS versions.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the solution, but you can try installing the [latest RDC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084) for Windows XP and then connecting. Also try connecting to another Windows Server 2003 x64 machine (if possible on another domain/Workgroup) and compare the results.

It may be that for Windows XP SP2 and below, you are able to connect since Windows Sever 2k3 may be treating the RDC client as legacy and may be cutting down on some new security features.

Make sure you add the user in Windows 2k3 x64 to System -> Remote ->Select Remote Users. Try with local as well as domain users.

Comment: +1, Install [XP SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5b33b5a8-5e76-401f-be08-1e1555d4f3d4&displaylang=en), the latest [RDC Client](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084), and enable [CredSSP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951608/).